Is there a way to use the dev versions of other Drupal modules in GitLab CI but stable as the install dependency?
I maintain a couple of contrib modules that are pretty closely linked.
When a user runs composer require drupal/mymodule_with_dependencies, I want them to get stable dependencies for all of the modules.
But, when I run the tests on GitLab CI, I want to always use the latest dev of all dependencies.
It seems that it isn't possible to do this in composer.json because I have to specify the dependency version as stable or dev.
Is there some way to somehow specify both? (dev when testing, stable when installing)

If you’re testing against a different version than your end users will be using, is that a fair test? Doesn’t that negate the guarantees automated testing gives you in the first place? (Genuine questions, you might have a particular workflow in mind which makes what I’m thinking irrelevant)

@Clive In this case, Module A implements a library that I don't control.  Module B is build on top of Module A.  The underlying library is updated frequently and often has gaps in the documentation, so library updates in Module A break Module B. Right now my approach is to release a new stable version each time I get the new library update working.
